LeaveOneOut CV for Bandwidth selection of Kernel Density Estimation
I've taken this code in order to try optimization of bandwidth_selection with GridSearchCV (while implementing LeaveOneOut logics within this CV: "LeaveOneOut() is equivalent to KFold(n_splits=n)")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# Plot a 1D density example
N = 100
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),
                    np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N))))[:, np.newaxis]

X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

true_dens = (0.3 * norm(0, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0])
             + 0.7 * norm(5, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill(X_plot[:, 0], true_dens, fc='black', alpha=0.2,
        label='input distribution')

##Note: LeaveOneOut() is equivalent to KFold(n_splits=n) and LeavePOut(p=1) where n is the number of samples.
kf = KFold(n_splits= len(X), shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for kernel in ['epanechnikov', 'tophat', 'gaussian']:
    kde = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(kernel = kernel),{'bandwidth': np.linspace(0.1, 50, 20)}, cv = kf).fit(X)
    log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)
    ax.plot(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens), '-',
            label="kernel = '{0}'".format(kernel))

ax.text(6, 0.38, "N={0} points".format(N))

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.plot(X[:, 0], -0.005 - 0.01 * np.random.random(X.shape[0]), '+k')

ax.set_xlim(-4, 9)
ax.set_ylim(-0.02, 0.4)
plt.show()

resulting in

but I suppose/see, that LeaveOneOut is very time-consuming method... How can it be implemented in tree-like manner for speed? , or if GridSearchCV already is implemented like a tree?, or perhaps I just lack memory? -- How to speed up bandwidth_optimization ?? (if somebody knows?)
P.S. algorithm that chooses the optimal bandwidth, wiki, overall, Custom estimator

bw = bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-1, 1, 100) with further passing param {'bandwidth': bw}, works better for fitting... still speed is needed

well, answer: "The bandwidth is kernel.covariance_factor() multiplied by the std of the sample that you are using." -- seems self-explaining, as well as PythonDataScienceHandbook

... as so as it is faster approach

Q: Which is the algorithm that KernelDensity(kernel = 'gaussian') makes use of? A: By default it is the kd_tree algorithm. -- such my Q is answered in comments. So, trees will not speed-up, and really it is memory-consuming algo
